# Embedding PowerBi for customers with RLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have a portal for our customers on our website. We want to embed reports here so our customers can see their data. Also we don't want our customers to need a PowerBi license/give them a license.

This means we we will use the 'App owns data' scenario also known as [embedding for customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedding).

We use a on premise analysis server with a live connection.

As mentioned earlier we will use row level security to make sure our customers only see their own data and nothing else. But reading through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security) I read:

> The effective identity that is provided for the username property must
> be a Windows user with permissions on the Analysis Services server.

I have tested some scenarios and it seems indeed like an external user will only be able to view the embedded reports if they have an account in our Active Directory.

This seems really counter intuitive, this would mean I have to create an account for the external customer in our Active Directory.

**Did I choose the right way here for giving our customers access to our reports or am I missing something here?**

Comment: This remark concerns live connections to Analysis Services. What is your data source and storage mode?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov forgot to mention, we have a on premise analysis server and we do use a live connection.

Comment: In this case yes, you have to create accounts for each of your customers in your AD. This is how the integrated RLS works. Otherwise you must implement your own solution to filter the data based on the current user when embedding the report (and probably hide the filters pane to not allow the user to remove these filters).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Live connection to Analysis Services, you have to create accounts for each of your customers in your AD. This is how the integrated RLS works. Otherwise you must implement your own solution to [filter the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters) based on the current user when embedding the report (and probably [hide the filters pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/configure-report-settings#panes) to not allow the user to remove these filters).